# Discord Bot is auto stopping

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My discord bot is auto stopping for some reason. It turns off after around an hour of inactivity. I don't know what code to send for that so if you need code to answer the question tell me and I will post which files you need.
Thanks
Here is the code, For some reason I have to add more words to post this.
bot.js

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');

var logger = require('winston');

var auth = require('./auth.json');

var fs = require('fs')


// Configure logger settings

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);

logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {

colorize: true
});

logger.level = 'debug';

// Initialize Discord Bot

var bot = new Discord.Client({

token: auth.token,

autorun: true

});

bot.on('ready', function (evt) {

logger.info('Connected');

logger.info('Logged in as: ');

logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

var cmd
let ndata = fs.readFileSync('./lore.json');
var data = require('./lore.json');
const { threadId } = require('worker_threads');
const { syncBuiltinESMExports } = require('module');
let oldCmd, place
const d = new Date()
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, guild, evt,) {
    var args = message.substring(0).split('poiafhdkadhf');
    fs.writeFile('./lore.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function writeJSON(err) {})
    cmd = args[0]
    args = args.splice(0);
    oldCmd = cmd
    cmd = cmd.toLowerCase()
    place = 5
    ndata = fs.readFileSync('./lore.json');
if(oldCmd.substring(0, 5) == "sage:"){
if(attribute() == "sage:age"){
    editUser(userID, {"years": oldCmd.slice(place + 5)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"years": oldCmd.slice(place + 5)})
    
}
if(attribute() == "name"){
    editUser(userID, {"name": oldCmd.slice(place + 4)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"name": oldCmd.slice(place + 4)})
}
if(attribute() == "gender"){
    editUser(userID, {"gender": oldCmd.slice(place + 6)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"gender": oldCmd.slice(place + 6)})
}
if(attribute() == "pronouns"){
    editUser(userID, {"pronouns": oldCmd.slice(place + 8)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"pronouns": oldCmd.slice(place + 8)})
}
if(attribute() == "personality"){
    editUser(userID, {"personality": oldCmd.slice(place + 11)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"personality": oldCmd.slice(place + 11)})
}
if(attribute() == "race"){
    editUser(userID, {"race": oldCmd.slice(place + 4)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"race": oldCmd.slice(place + 4)})
}
if(attribute() == "family"){
    editUser(userID, {"family": oldCmd.slice(place + 6)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"family": oldCmd.slice(place + 6)})
}
if(attribute() == "extra"){
    editUser(userID, {"extra": oldCmd.slice(place + 5)}, channelID = channelID)
    editUser(userID, {"extra": oldCmd.slice(place + 5)})
}
if(attribute() == "get"){
    if(oldCmd.substring(9).trim() == ''){
        var gotten = get(userID)
        if(gotten != null){
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: "name: " + gotten.name + "\nage: " + gotten.years + "\ngender: "  + gotten.gender + "\npronouns: " + gotten.pronouns + "\npersonality: " + gotten.personality + "\nrace: " + gotten.race + "\nfamily: " + gotten.family + "\nextra: " + gotten.extra
            })
        }
    } else {
        var gotten = get(oldCmd.substring(9).trim().replace("<", '').replace("@", '').replace(">", ''))
        bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: "name: " + gotten.name + "\nage: " + gotten.years + "\ngender: "  + gotten.gender + "\npronouns: " + gotten.pronouns + "\npersonality: " + gotten.personality + "\nrace: " + gotten.race + "\nfamily: " + gotten.family + "\nextra: " + gotten.extra
        })
    }
}
if(attribute() == "help"){
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: "Do Sage:name followed by your name, Sage:gender for gender, Sage:pronouns for pronouns, Sage:personality for personality, Sage:race for race, Sage:family for family, Sage:extra for extra, and Sage:age for your age\n\nUse Sage:get followed by a ping of whoever's lore you want to get\n\nUse Sage:help for these instructions"
    })
}
}
});

function editUser(identity, changes, channelID = null){
    data = require('./lore.json');
    console.log("edited")
    var count = 0
    var userE = false
    sleep(50)
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].id == identity){
            if(changes.name != null){
                data[i].name = changes.name
            }
            if(changes.years != null){
                data[i].years = changes.years
            } 
            if(changes.gender != null){
                data[i].gender = changes.gender
            }
            if(changes.pronouns != null){
                data[i].pronouns = changes.pronouns
            }
            if(changes.personality != null){
                data[i].personality = changes.personality
            }
            if(changes.race != null){
                data[i].race = changes.race
            }
            if(changes.family != null){
                data[i].family = changes.family
            }
            if(changes.extra != null){
                data[i].extra = changes.extra
            }
            userE = true
        }
    }
    if(!userE){
        data.push({id: String(identity),name: " ", years:" ", gender:" ", pronouns:" ", personality:" ", race:" ",family:" ", extra:" "})
    }
    fs.writeFile('./lore.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), function writeJSON(err) {})
    if(channelID != null){
    bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: "Saved"
    })
}
}
function attribute(){
    const attributes = ["name", "sage:age", "gender", "pronouns", "personality", "race", "family", "relationship", "extra", "get", "help"]
    for(let x in attributes){
        if(cmd.indexOf(attributes[x]) != -1){
            return attributes[x]
        }
    }
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

function get(identity){
    for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].id == identity){
            return data[i]
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

package.json

```
{"name":"Sage Lore","version":"1.0.0","description":"My First Discord Bot","main":"bot.js","author":"Your Name","dependencies":{"@discordjs/rest":"^0.4.1","discord-api-types":"^0.33.1","discord.io":"https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6","winston":"^3.7.2"}}
```

auth.json

```
{

"token": not putting my token

}
```

Comment: Send all the code. The problem sounds like the code is being run on something like Replit which tends to auto-stop these things after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's because command prompt auto closes, to prevent it you can fix it by opening command prompt with windows + r and then typing cmd /K

Answer (score 0):

## Your hosting does not provide 24/7 hosting

The issue must be coming from your hosting provider. From what you've stated, it sounds like you're **running your code on [Replit](https://replit.com)**. This service *can* host projects 24/7 but does not do this for free. This is because after an hour of inactivity, the repl will automatically enter a sleeping state. The documentation states the following:

> *Once deployed, the server will continue to run in the background, even after you close the browser tab. The server will stay awake and active until an **hour** after its last request, after which it will enter a sleeping stage.*

- [Deploying HTTP servers](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/deploying-http-servers)

This sleeping state will result in the repl shutting down. This also means that it will stop sending data to Discord, which in turn, stops the bot from running.

## Always-on repls

To avoid an issue like this, you must purchase a Hacker plan from them. As stated in the documentation:

> *Repls typically go to sleep after a period of inactivity. To make sure that your repl is restarted, you can use our Always-on functionality.*
>
> *Note that this function is currently only available on our Hacker plan.*

- [Enabling Always-on](https://docs.replit.com/hosting/enabling-always-on)

Therefore, unless you have the plan, Always-on is not available.

Comment: I'm hosting it from my computer using the command node bot.js

Comment: Does your computer automatically go to sleep after a set period of time? That might be the issue

Comment: No, I have it so it never turns off unless I do it